# What is better approach to bind an action?

Tags: jquery

```
$('body').delegate(".foo", 'click', function(){});
```

or

```
$(".foo").live('click', function(){});
```

I prefer second, but maybe is there any benefits to use first?

Comment: Another question, do you need the 'live' functionality? Else you could use the $(".foo").click( function() {}); syntax.

Comment: Yes, i need 'live' functionality. And i need it for whole document.

Comment: From the answers below, in short, use `delegate()`. I was looking at this just this morning actually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegate is like a revamped `live` in that it accomplishes the same task as `live` but without the associated shortcomings. Most notably `live` attaches to the document and has issues with chaining.

Delegate also has performance benefits compared to live, which is a plus.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you're going for. There exists different methods for different purposes.

- [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)
  Attach a handler to one or more events for all elements that match the selector, now or in the future, based on a specific set of root elements. **Delegate is an alternative to using the .live() method, allowing for each binding of event delegation to specific DOM elements.**
- [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
  Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current selector, now and in the future.
- [`bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
  Attach a handler to an event for the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the difference between live and delegate is :

> - live function can't be used in
>     chaining. live function needs to be
>     used directly on a selector/element.
> - There is one more difference in
>     terms of performance, if the context
>     is not specified with the live
>     function. Context means you are
>     setting the search limit within a
>     specific node. If you don't specify
>     the context with live function then it
>     attaches the handler to the document
>     by default and when executed it
>     traverse through the DOM which causes
>     a performance issue.